# Javascript play Youtube video gets error Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy

Tags: javascript, youtube

I'm using Javascript to trigger autoplay Youtube videos on my website. The code works fine but I get the following errors in the browser console each time the user clicks to play a Youtube video.

The JS code:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.js-youtube').forEach(elOIframe => {

    const elCover = elOIframe.querySelector('.js-iframe-cover');
    const elIframe = elOIframe.querySelector(".js-iframe");
    
    elCover.addEventListener('click', function() {
        elCover.style.opacity = '0';
        elIframe.src += '?autoplay=1';
    });
    
    elCover.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
        elCover.remove();
    });
});
```

The errors in the console in SAFARI:

```
[Error] Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'require-trusted-types-for'.

[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.youtube.com/api/stats/atr?ns=yt&el=embedded&cpn=y-gsz15JN1OEQ7im&ver=2&cmt=0&fs=0&rt=0&euri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2F&lact=9830&cl=543294211&mos=0&volume=100&cbrand=apple&cbr=Safari&cbrver=15.5&c=WEB_EMBEDDED_PLAYER&cver=1.20230625.00.00&cplayer=UNIPLAYER&cos=Macintosh&cosver=10_15_7&cplatform=DESKTOP&epm=1&hl=fr_FR&cr=ES&len=137&fexp=23983296%2C24007246%2C24080738%2C24135310%2C24362614%2C24364789%2C24366065%2C24366917%2C24380264%2C24383853%2C24384175%2C24388285%2C24388529%2C24415864%2C24439361%2C24470719%2C24559328%2C39324104&muted=0&docid=cY4TsJ2GZG4 due to access control checks.
    yz (base.js:1893:173)
    (fonction anonyme) (base.js:1878)
    (fonction anonyme) (base.js:6068:193)
    (fonction anonyme) (base.js:8432:573)
    RZa (base.js:6068)
    (fonction anonyme) (base.js:11362:654)
    YZa (base.js:6083:85)
    d_a (base.js:6100)
    (fonction anonyme) (base.js:11570:100)
    (fonction anonyme) (base.js:11466:105)
    (fonction anonyme) (base.js:9710:82)
    (fonction anonyme) (base.js:4225)
    (fonction anonyme) (www-embed-player.js:1777:112)
    Tw (www-embed-player.js:1813)
    (fonction anonyme) (www-embed-player.js:1820:186)
    (fonction anonyme) (www-embed-player.js:858)
    
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/log_event?alt=json&key=AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8 due to access control checks.
    xl (www-embed-player.js:903:136)
    ul (www-embed-player.js:888)
    Pp (www-embed-player.js:1252:149)
    (fonction anonyme) (www-embed-player.js:1158)
    (fonction anonyme) (www-embed-player.js:1247:100)
    e (www-embed-player.js:1262:166)
    (fonction anonyme) (www-embed-player.js:1270)
    promiseReactionJob

[Error] Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'require-trusted-types-for'. (x4)
```

Comment: This error has nothing to do with **multiple** videos.  It's a shame you didn't simplify and reduce your question before posting it to SO.